# Selenium - Log messages to selenium RC log through Javascript - Possible?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am trying to log messages to Selenium RC's log through Javascript. For  example

```
seleniumRc.log('Statement');
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!
DashK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use Selenium's internal logger.  The only question is where the LOG object is located, but I think it's on the "selenium" object.  Try `selenium.LOG.info('blah blah blah')`, or perhaps `window.top.LOG.info('blah blah blah')`.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, in Selenium IDE 1.3.0, the Selenium object has a doEcho function, which is very useful. It also writes to the Selenium IDE log.

If you ever find yourself writing a User extension, the following syntax can be used:

```
Selenium.prototype.getSomething = function(location,text) {
    this.doEcho(text);
    return "Something";
}
```